# How to combine two CSV files into the same graph with d3js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a csv file "data_good.csv" with the simple format : `date,value` ("date" here is just a number, not date format.)

I've just started using d3js and here is the code i'm using for the graph :

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = screen.width - 200,
    height = 200;
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#body_d3_graph").append("svg").attr("class","my_svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data
d3.csv("tmp/data_good.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("fill", "green")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

It's working as expected with several green bars.

But now i have another csv file `("tmp/data_bad.csv")` and i would like to have it as a red bar on top of the green one. According to their key "date". (There is no date without value : data_good.csv and data_bad.csv have the same number of lines.)

Comment: Is your question how to *read* multiple files or how to *draw* multiple bars from different data structures?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should separate logic which draws chart and logic which loads a file.

**Also you have to group bars and separate drawing axes from bars.**

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = screen.width - 200,
    height = 200;
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#body_d3_graph").append("svg").attr("class","my_svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var drawAxes = function(data) {
// add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
}

var drawChart = function(data) {
  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg
     .append('g')
     .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("fill", "green")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
}

// get the data
d3.csv("tmp/data_good.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  drawChart(data);
});
```

Then if you want to preserve domain scaling to be defined only by "good data" you can abstract it too and use only in "good data reader".
Remember to draw axes when changing scales.

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = screen.width - 200,
    height = 200;
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);
          
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#body_d3_graph").append("svg").attr("class","my_svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var drawAxes = function(data) {
// add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
}

var setDomains = function(data) {
  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  drawAxes();
}

var drawChart = function(data) {
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("fill", "green")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
}

// get the data
d3.csv("tmp/data_good.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  setDomains(data);
  drawChart(data);
});

d3.csv("tmp/data_bad.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  drawChart(data);
});
```